# pytest assert if method inside of context manager was called

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest, python-unittest, influxdb

I have implemented interface for InfluxDB, based on theirs examples. It uses writting to DB inside context_manager:

```
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, Point, WriteOptions


class InfluxInterface:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__client = None
        self.bucket_name = 'bucket_name'

    def connect(self, url=IFDB_URL, token=IFDB_TOKEN, org=IFDB_ORG, timeout=IFDB_TIMEOUT, debug=False):
        self.__client = InfluxDBClient(url=url, token=token, org=org, timeout=timeout, debug=debug)

    def is_connected(self):
        return self.__client is not None

    def insert_stuff(self, stuff: List[Tag]):
        if not self.is_connected():
            return

        points = []

        for item in stuff:
            point = Point('measurment_name').time(item.item_ts).tag('tag_name', item.tag).field('field_name', item.field)
            points.append(point)

        with self.__client.write_api(write_options=WriteOptions(batch_size=5000, flush_interval=5000),
                                     success_callback=self.batch_write_success,
                                     error_callback=self.batch_write_error,
                                     retry_callback=self.batch_write_retry) as write_api:
            write_api.write(bucket=self.bucket_name, record=points)
            # Write is not returning anything (returning None)
```

Now, I want to unittest it using `pytest`, but I am failing..

First thing I want to do is, to mock `is_connected()`, to allways return `True`. I do it this way:

```
mocker.patch.object(InfluxInterface, "is_connected").return_value = True
```

My goal is to mock `write_api.write(bucket=self.bucket_name, record=points)`, because I do not want to wrtite into DB, or connect to DB, or even have the need to have DB as a predispositon to unittest this stuff. I only want to assert if `write_api.write` was called with correct arguments.  So I have prepared this test method:

```
import pytest
from my_lib.influx_lib import InfluxInterface

class TestInfluxInterface:
    def test_insert_stuff(self, mocker):
        # influx_client = mocker.patch('my_lib.influx_lib.InfluxDBClient', autospec=True)
        # Is connected, return True
        fake_is_connected = mocker.patch.object(InfluxInterface, "is_connected").return_value = True

        # fake_client = mocker.patch.object(InfluxInterface, '__client', autospec=True)

        fake_write_api = mocker.patch.object(InfluxInterface, '_InfluxInterface__client').return_value.__enter__.write

        test_connector = InfluxInterface()
        test_list = [test_item_1, test_item_2, test_item_3]
        result = test_connector.insert_stuff(test_list)
        fake_write_api.assert_called_once_with(bucket=self.bucket_name, record=points)
```

As you can see in the comments of the code above, I have been trying various different approaches to mock the context manager and `write_api.write` method properly. But none of that works.

---

Edit:

This is, how far I managed to get so far:

```
def test_insert_tags(self, mocker):
    influx_client = mocker.patch('my_lib.influx_lib.InfluxDBClient')  # , autospec=True)
    # Is connected, return Status.ok
    mocker.patch.object(InfluxInterface, "is_connected").return_value = True

    test_connector = InfluxInterface()
    fake_write_api = mocker.MagicMock()
    test_connector._InfluxInterface__client = influx_client
    # test_connector._InfluxInterface__client.write_api.return_value = mocker.Mock(w_api=fake_write_api, __enter__=influx_client, __exit__=mocker.Mock())
    # test_connector._InfluxInterface__client.write_api.return_value = mocker.Mock(__enter__=fake_write_api, __exit__=mocker.Mock())
    # test_connector._InfluxInterface__client.write_api.return_value.__enter__.w_api.write = fake_write_api

    test_taglist = [analog_test_tag, discrete_test_tag, string_test_tag]
    result = test_connector.insert_tags(test_taglist, RecordType.all_values)

    print(f'influx_client has calls: {influx_client.write_api.mock_calls}')
    print(f'fake_write_api has calls: {fake_write_api.mock_calls}')
    print(f'fake_write_api.write has calls: {fake_write_api.write.mock_calls}')

    fake_write_api.write.assert_called_once()
    assert result.result_status.status_code == Tconf.status_ok.status_code
```

And the code is actually run, only assert is not meet. (All 3 commented calls to set `return_value` pass, but `fake_write_api` is not called in each of those cases.)

This is the result of test when it is run as the code above.

```
influx_client has calls:
 [call(write_options=<influxdb_client.client.write_api.WriteOptions object at 0x7f8d9e3bf580>, success_callback=<bound method InfluxInterface.batch_write_success of <my_lib.influx_lib.InfluxInterface object at 0x7f8d9e34d6c0>>, error_callback=<bound method InfluxInterface.batch_write_error of <my_lib.influx_lib.InfluxInterface object at 0x7f8d9e34d6c0>>, retry_callback=<bound method InfluxInterface.batch_write_retry of <my_lib.influx_lib.InfluxInterface object at 0x7f8d9e34d6c0>>),
  call().__enter__(),
  call().__enter__().write(bucket='bucket_name', record=[<influxdb_client.client.write.point.Point object at 0x7f8d9e3bd690>, <influxdb_client.client.write.point.Point object at 0x7f8d9e3bd6f0>]),
  call().__exit__(None, None, None)]
fake_write_api has calls: []
fake_write_api.write has calls: []
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just need to assert and for this I used the mock_calls. See example below:

```
assert influx_client.mock_calls[2] == call().__enter__().write(...)
```

Mocking it seems harder.